# Javalin webserver loads config from another webserver

Tags: java, kotlin, jetty, javalin

I got this server where I am loading a couple different jars as plugins. 2 of these jars use a Javalin, Jetty webserver for some functionality. Currently my plugin is for some reason loading the `io.javalin.core.JavalinConfig` from the other jar and this is causing conflicts as it will also complain about not being able to find the webfiles that are in the jar file.

> [13:46:30 WARN]: [ItemSorter] Loaded class io.javalin.core.JavalinConfig from Storefront v2.0-SNAPSHOT which is not a depend, softdepend or loadbefore of this plugin.
>   [13:46:30 WARN]: [ItemSorter] Plugin ItemSorter v0.01 generated an exception while executing task 221                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Static resource directory with path: '/web' does not exist. Depending on your setup, empty folders might not get copied to classpath.                                                                                       at io.javalin.http.staticfiles.JettyResourceHandler.getResourcePath(JettyResourceHandler.kt:59) ~[?:?]                  at io.javalin.http.staticfiles.JettyResourceHandler.addStaticFileConfig(JettyResourceHandler.kt:27) ~[?:?]              at io.javalin.core.JavalinConfig.addStaticFiles(JavalinConfig.java:122) ~[?:?]                                          at io.javalin.core.JavalinConfig.addStaticFiles(JavalinConfig.java:115) ~[?:?]                                          at io.javalin.core.JavalinConfig.addStaticFiles(JavalinConfig.java:111) ~[?:?]

Snippet of loading my javalin:

```
app = Javalin.create(config -> {
        config.addStaticFiles("/web");
        config.showJavalinBanner = false;
        config.requestCacheSize = 30000L;
    }).start(config.getInt("port"));
```

Snippet of the other plugin loading javalin:

```
val app = Javalin.create().start(7000)
```

Anyone have any kind of ideas as to seperate their loadings?

Answer (score 0):

The path you provide to `addStaticFiles()` method is a fully qualified path name.

The error is telling you that you don't have a directory (or file) on your filesystem at `/web` (which would be a directory called "web" off the root of your filesystem)

Make the path point to a real resource location that actually exists.